# Pronouns in non-defining relative clauses

Tags: grammar

Relative clauses:
We can remove the pronoun when the thing or person is the *object* of the verb.

Can we also use this rule in ***Non-defining relative clauses***????

For example: Are these two sentences correct?

1. This was also the philosophy promoted by X in his famous book *Small is Beautiful*, published in the 1970s.
2. This was also the philosophy promoted by X in his famous book *Small is Beautiful*, ***which was*** published in the 1970s. (Can we say "Which was" has been removed from the 1 sentence??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] *This was also the philosophy promoted by X in his famous book Small is*
> *Beautiful,* [*published in the 1970s*].
>
> [2] *This was also the philosophy promoted by X in his famous book Small is*
> *Beautiful,* [*which was published in the 1970s*].

The simple answer is no. Generally, "that" can be omitted in *defining* relative clauses providing it is not functioning as subject of the relative clause. But that's certainly not the case with non-defining relatives, which do not permit "that" but only *wh* relative words which cannot be omitted. In any case, your first example does not actually contain a relative clause.

Although your examples have similar meanings, and their subordinate clauses both refer to  X's famous book, only [2] contains a genuine relative clause: in [1] "published in the 1970's" is not a relative clause that has its relative word and finite verb omitted, but a different type of clause altogether called a past-participial clause.

Note that the past-participial clause is a bare passive, as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase.